# Why do we use let{} as null checking in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Why do we use exactly let{} as null checking in Kotlin?

Aren't other scope functions suitable for this? They do pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

It's an idiom. When everybody usually does things in basically the same way, it makes code easier to read and follow because your brain has to do less work to comprehend it. You can immediately grasp what's happening when you see an idiomatic pattern without having to reason through all its logic.

The reason `let` is the natural choice out of the scope functions, I think:

1. You usually only need to do this kind of null-check so you can do something with the non-null object. If you just wanted to call something on the non-null object, you could have just used `?.doWhatever()` instead of `?.run { doWhatever() }`. This rules out `run` and `apply` for readability reasons. `run { doSomething(this) }` is considered a little more awkward than `let { doSomething(it) }`.
2. Not always, but often, you want to do something with the return value of whatever function you're passing the non-null object to. This rules out `also`.

And `with` can't be used with `?.` safe invoke since it is a top level function with no receiver.

Those other functions `run`, `apply`, and `also` could be the best choice under some circumstances, but in most cases they have no readability advantage over `let` and so you may as well use the idiomatic choice.

Comment: personally I often find `?.let { ... }` less readable than a more traditional `if (x != null)`, but I guess it's subjective

Comment: @user2340612 `if (x != null)` is the preferred form when working with local variables and function parameters, and it's recommended in the Kotlin coding conventions document, IIRC. But it doesn't work for most properties.

Comment: The `if` form has a race condition: what if `x` changes after the check? (It could be changed by code inside the `if` branch, or from another thread if it's not local.) Whereas inside `let`, `it` is guaranteed not to change. The `let` form is also simpler and more efficient when you're dealing with a complex expression rather than just a simple variable. But yes, when neither of those apply, then the `if` form is probably more familiar.